# android gridview equal size cell

Tags: android, xml, gridview

i am trying to make a timer application for practice, and i am running into an issue where the gridview doesn't have the same size as the others.

this is part of the code

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/passwordField"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/two" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/three" /> </GridLayout>
```

there are more buttons after that, but this is all i needed to show right now
as you can see from the image:
[image]

it doesn't have the same cell size, where the 3rd Column is larger than the others.
What should I do to fix this problem?

I had RelativeLayout before with everything in the correct place, but the button wasn't stretching out to fill the width.

Comment: You can try using android:weight attribute in button views to assign equal weight/size to all views

Comment: change your grid layout width to wrap content

Comment: there is only layout_columnweight which is for api 22 and above, is that what you mean?

Comment: You can use the gridlayout support library to get layout_columnweight for < api 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout_columnWeight` is the missing piece. Note that you can simplify the Button declarations as well:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordField"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addInput"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:onClick="addInput"
            android:text="@string/two" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:onClick="addInput"
            android:text="@string/three" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: i did actually try it before, but nothing really changed. i ended up changing all the buttons with  android:layout_columnWeight="1" and got it working, i guess i will have to apply it to every single buttons within this gridlayout.

Comment: Yep you'll need it for all child views. For your "0" button you can use layout_columnweight="3" to span the entire width.

Answer (score 2):

apply this attribute to each of your button xml

```
     android:layout_columnWeight="1"
```